# DocuSign PHP Api Client FoldersApi List error

Tags: php, docusignapi

Not sure if anyone else has noticed or perhaps it is just something in my environment, but whenever I try to use anything related to the FoldersApi class I get this error:

```
FatalErrorException in FoldersApi.php line 321:
syntax error, unexpected 'list' (T_LIST), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

It seems that you cannot declare function list() as list is a reserved keyword:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Changing the function definition from:

```
public function list($account_id)
```

to:

```
public function listFolders($account_id)
```

solves the issue.

Is this the case or am I missing something? Running PHP 5.5.31

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into it - this is because `list` is a reserved keyword, and the people from DocuSign probably never did any testing.